# Find the stationary point(s) of the curve $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2-x+5$ and determine their nature

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the stationary point(s) of the curve $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2-x+5$ and determine their nature

I've tried this question multiple times. I'm beginning to think the answer is just "There are no stationary points".

Answer (score 1):

A stationary point is a point where the derivative is zero, so the first thing to do is to solve the equation $f'(x)=6x^2-6x-1=0$.

By solving the quadratic equation we get two stationary points $x_1=(3-\sqrt{15})/6$ and $x_2=(3+\sqrt{15})/6$. Moreover $f'(x)$ is negative inside the interval $(x_1,x_2)$ and positive outside. This means that $f$ is increasing in $(-\infty,x_1)$, $f$ is decreasing in $(x_1,x_2)$ and $f$ is increasing in $(x_2,+\infty)$.

Therefore $x_1$ is a local maximum point and $x_2$ is a local minimum point.

Comment: How did know to use a second derivative?

Comment: @GregorH To solve $6x^2-6x-1=0$  you should use the formula for quadratic equations!

Comment: Of course! I knew there was something I was forgetting. Thank you

Comment: @GregorH Any further doubts?